# QLabel appears grayed out inside QWidgetAction

Tags: qt, qmenu, qwidgetaction

I am using a `QWidgetAction` to create a `QMenu` "item" that has a `QLabel` and a `QLineEdit`. These are added to a `QHBoxLayout` which is added to a `QWidget` which is set as the default in the `QWidgetAction`.

The end result is that everything works, except the `QLabel` is displayed with grayed out text, as if disabled. Calling `setEnabled(true)` on everything mentioned above has no effect. The only thing that seems to help is forcing the text color of the `QLabel` using a stylesheet or rich text, but it's impossible to match the color of the other, regular, menu items. What am I missing?

Comment: Tested this with Qt 5.12.0 MinGW 64-bit on Windows 10, result looks fine to me (if I understood the question correctly). Screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/ChTF6Vq). Code: [link](https://pastebin.com/z2TbZcrb). Please provide more info, such as source code and system info to help troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Noticed that your question is about setting default widget and not subclassing as im my previous comment. Checked that approach - same result, label text not greyed out. Only difference is that this way the widget action can't be shown in the menu and toolbar simultaneously (as docummented "If a QWidgetAction with only a default widget is added to two toolbars at the same time then the default widget is shown only in the first toolbar the action was added to."). Code: [link](https://pastebin.com/Qwb47w7f).